# Visual Studio 2010 - Coded UI Test - Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on my Windows XP. I'm trying to record a Coded UI Test via Coded UI Test Builder, but I always got "Access is denied" message, or "The control is not available or not valid". I got the same message when I'm trying to record about click on the Start menu or typeing into Notepad.

I have read a lot of topics about this problem but I haven't found good solution.

Comment: What is your Service Pack version? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742(v=vs.100).aspx) only WinXp SP3 is compatible.

Comment: The Service Pack version is SP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the computer solved the problem.